# Тестирование GUI Qt приложения

Tags: qt, gui, тестирование, юнит-тесты

Подскажите пожалуйста какие-нибудь хорошие маны, статьи по написанию тестов для GUI в Qt - приложении. Например, для уже готового приложения (сырцы есть) мне нужно написать тест (скрипт?) для регистрации пользователя, sign in/out. Тестированием никогда не занимался, потому и не знаю про такие вещи.

Answer (score 4):

Бланшетт или Шлее (на выбор): книжка по Qt. Есть глава по автоматическому тестированию. Как раз основы.
Эта же примерно информация доступна в Qt Assistant, но на английском.